# How to import library in my template python script? (not working like in vim like in the repl)

Tags: external-command, plugin-vimwiki, python

I have a python script for generating templates that's being invoked by this line in my vimrc file:

```
autocmd BufNewFile ~/Documents/wiki/diary/*.mkd :silent 0r !vimwiki-diary-template.py
```

That works.  Vim uses that script in creating a template for each new vimwiki diary file.

But I'm trying to make it more robust and it's not working:

Adding

```
from tasklib import TaskWarrior
```

causes

```
ImportError: No module named tasklib
```

But this `from tasklib import TaskWarrior` works in both my REPL as well as in my taskwiki plugin, just not in my custom template script.

I can eliminate that import error by setting

```
sys.path = ['', '/home/alec/.local/bin', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/home/alec/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

before trying to `import tasklib` but then it just produces a different error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alec/bin/vimwiki-diary-template.py", line 6, in <module>
    from tasklib import TaskWarrior
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tasklib/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .backends import TaskWarrior
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tasklib/backends.py", line 2, in <module>
    import copy
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/copy.py", line 52, in <module>
    import weakref
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/weakref.py", line 50
    .format(type(meth))) from None
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

...which doesn't make any sense to me.  A syntax error in `/usr/lib/python3.7/weakref.py`?

Vim is compiled with python3 support:

```
+comments          +libcall           -python            +visualextra
+conceal           +linebreak         +python3           +viminfo
Linking: gcc   -Wl,-E  -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -o vim   -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lSM -lICE -lXpm -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE  -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux  -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl  -L/usr/lib -llua5.2 -Wl,-E  -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.28/CORE -lperl -ldl -lm -lpthread -lcrypt  -L/usr/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.7m -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -ltcl8.6 -ldl -lz -lpthread -lm
```

What's going on here?

How do I use this `tasklib` library in my `vimwiki-diary-template.py` template?

Comment: Doing `!file` will just execute the file; nothing relevant to vim's support of python3 there. Does running the file at the command line like `./vimwiki-diary-template.py` work the way you want?

Comment: What's the shebang line in your `vimwiki-diary-template.py` script? What does `:!python3 --version` says (or the binary in the shebang line)? I imagine it might not be running the python 3.7 interpreter that you think it is...

Comment: omg, thank you!  yes, the script was simply using #!/usr/bin/python which was version 2.7.  Thanks for point out the shebang!

Comment: @filbranden you and I had the same thought; you just articulated better :)

Comment: nice, I didn't even realize (or had only vaguely heard) that it was possible to do `:! some-script.py` from inside vim... which I presume is what `!file`  was referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Specifying the python version in the script like `#!/usr/bin/python3` (instead of just `#!/usr/bin/python`) solves the problem.